# AzureAD - I'm having issues with retrieving user information, specifically the employee number, when I authenticate through AzureAD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js

I have a React front-end that authenticates the user and obtains an access token with the scope for my API. I use this token to validate the session when making requests in my back-end, and I was able to validate the user. However, I couldn't retrieve the employee number, which I need for some configurations. Did I miss configuring something in my Azure? Is there a simpler way to obtain the employee number?

I'm using passport.js, here's my configuration:

```
const passportConfig = {
  credentials: {
    tenantID: process.env.TENANT_ID,
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  },
  metadata: {
    authority: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
    discovery: '.well-known/openid-configuration',
    version: 'v2.0',
  },
  settings: {
    validateIssuer: true,
    passReqToCallback: true,
    loggingLevel: 'error',
    loggingNoPII: true,
  },
};

const bearerStrategy = new passportAzureAd.BearerStrategy({
  identityMetadata: `https://${passportConfig.metadata.authority}/${passportConfig.credentials.tenantID}/${passportConfig.metadata.version}/${passportConfig.metadata.discovery}`,
  issuer: `https://${passportConfig.metadata.authority}/${passportConfig.credentials.tenantID}/${passportConfig.metadata.version}`,
  clientID: passportConfig.credentials.clientID,
  audience: passportConfig.credentials.clientID,
  validateIssuer: passportConfig.settings.validateIssuer,
  passReqToCallback: passportConfig.settings.passReqToCallback,
  loggingLevel: passportConfig.settings.loggingLevel,
  loggingNoPII: passportConfig.settings.loggingNoPII,
}, (req, token, done) => {
  /**
   * If needed, pass down additional user info to route using the second argument below.
   * This information will be available in the req.user object.
   */
  return done(null, {}, token);
});
```

I attempted to make a request from the back-end to the Microsoft Graph API using the same access token, but it threw an error, indicating that the audience is invalid, which I believe is caused because the token doesn't have that scope, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

To get the employee number from the Azure AD access token, you need to request the `user.employeeId` scope. You can do this by adding the following to the `scopes` array in your passport.js configuration:

```
scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default', 'user.employeeId']
```

Once you have done this, you will be able to retrieve the employee number from the `req.user` object in your code.

Here is the way im able to get details for user

Created a file (e.g., `auth.js`) to configure Passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const OIDCStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;

const config = {
  identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration',
  clientID: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  responseType: 'code id_token',
  responseMode: 'form_post',
  redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
  clientSecret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
  validateIssuer: false,
  passReqToCallback: true,
  scope: ['openid', 'profile'],
};

passport.use(
  new OIDCStrategy(config, (req, iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {
    return done(null, profile);
  })
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  done(null, obj);
});
```

**Result**

[image]